# how to ignore returned error in GO

Tags: go

I have started learning Go today.
One thing that makes me crazy, it's the `err` returned parameter.

Let's assume I need to nest few functions. like this:

```
return string(json.Marshal(MyData))
```

or more complex example:

```
return func1(func2(func3(MyData)))
```

Is it really necessary to write:

```
tmp1 , _ = func3(MyData)
tmp2 , _ = func2(tmp1)
tmp3 , _ = func1(tmp2)
return tmp3
```

That's annoying!
Is there any way to make the code looks cleaner?

Comment: Short answer: do not ignore errors in Go

Comment: Yes, there is a way to make it much cleaner: Add error handling. Ignoring error is the complete opposite of clean code.

Comment: Simply saying "Do NOT..." is not an answer to the question, although the title and the post are not asking the exact same question. I got to say that adding error handing is not making the code "cleaner", but only more robust. However, maybe the OP is only playing around, or working with some simple one-shot scripting tasks.  Or simply because he can live with the potential consequences. Anyhow, the OP's original question is valid. Both Rust and Haskell provide some way to leave the error to runtime (in Rust, `unwrap`; in Haskell, it depending on what error handling mechanism you are using)

Answer (score -3, accepted):

The *real* answer is: Don't.

Never just ignore the errors.

Seriously. The errors are there for a reason. If a function returns an error,
it almost always means that it's possible, during the operation of your program,
*even if it's 100% bug-free*, for the function to fail. And if it does,
you don't usually want to just keep going as if nothing happened.

If you're absolutely sure that you're using a function in a way that ensures that it will *never* return a non-nil error (unless there's a bug in your program, and there always is), you might want to write a `Must`-style function like in the [`template` package](http://golang.org/pkg/html/template/#Must) which panics with the returned error value.

Error handling is not noise. It's not clutter. It's not something you want
to get rid of. If it looks like 50% of your program is error
handling, that's because 50% of your program is, and should be, error handling.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I'll try to follow it.
Probably GO has different mindset than PHP-JS.

Comment: Except in the case where the documentation explicitly says that the function returns `nil`: e.g. `strings.WriteString()`: "WriteString appends the contents of s to b's buffer. It returns the length of s and a nil error."

Comment: This is not an answer to the question ask, it's an opinion. There are legitimate reasons to ignore the error value.

Comment: Absolutely agree @SkyKelsey. Dogmatic purism is not something to be proud of.

Comment: Absolutely you can ignore errors in TESTING, where a panic is okay. Ergo httptest.NewRequest (identical to http.NewRequest except it will panic instead of error) FOR TESTING.

Comment: This response is simplistic at best.  In real-world code in the wild, the right place to handle an error is almost never at the site of the call at which it occurred.  Within a function, it is typical for the response to all errors occurring within that function to be the same, thus unified error handling generates much cleaner code.  Much more often, however, the appropriate place to handle an error is several levels up the call stack; lower than that and it is not clear what to do with it.  Go may or may not have a good answer to the OP's question, but it is definitely a valid question.

Answer (score 7):

It is possible to define a function to ignore errors, but Go's lack of generics make it so you'd have to use interface{} and typecasts all over the place, losing a lot of static guarantees from the typechecker in the process. It is extremely ugly. Don't do this.

```
func ignoreError(val interface {}, err error) interface {} {
    return val
}
```

At every call to `ignoreError()` you would have to make a type cast to the expected return type.

[Playground example](http://play.golang.org/p/KGFF4mEkBg)

Answer (score 2):

One possible abstraction pattern you will often see is to use a generic error handler.

This doesn't prevent you from having to **deal** with error values, but it does **abstract** the handling of errors away from the rest of your code.

Note that abstractions like these are considered "non-idiomatic" Go, the "pure" way is to explicitly handle errors in-place. This panic-driven alternative can still be very useful though, especially for quickly prototyping a script where you just want to dump all the errors in a console or logfile.

For reusable packages, I would stick to the verbose explicit way though, because others will expect error-producing functions to actually return error values, rather than using a panic-recover mechanism.

```golang
package main

import (
    utils
)

func main() {
    defer func() {
        utils.Handle(func(err error) {
            // Handle errors in a generic way, 
            // for example using println, or writing to http 
        })
    }()

    var result, err := someFragileFunction()
    Check(err)
}
```

```golang
package utils

func Check(err error) {
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}

func Handle(handler func(err error))  {
    if r := recover(); r != nil {
        if err, ok := r.(error); ok {
            handler(err)
        } else {
            panic(r)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Took answer from [ReyCharles](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31027853/3040214), but made it generic so that you don't have to cast.

```
func IgnoreError[T any](val T, err error) T {
   return val
}
```